# FB graphics not loading?

Tags: facebook, button

I am trying to simply add the like button to my simple website and I don't get any graphics at all.  I went to AddThis and their implementation doesn't work either.  Is my system not setup correctly or am I making a rookie mistake.  Here is the code and all I get is a red box with the paragraph.
Thanks for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml: lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <title>Facebook button test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .content p {
            border: 1px solid red;
            position: relative;
        }
        .fb-root {
            border: 3px solid blue;
            height: 200px;
            width: 500px;
            padding: 1em;
            float: right;
        }
        .fb-like {
            border: 10px solid green;
            padding: 1em;
        }   
    </style>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <fb:like href="facebook.com/burgessfww" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

        <p> Some text to take up some space and see what's happening!</p>       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simple... but since I didn't test it You should!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml: lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

This seems to be your mistake: XMLNS:FB twice

xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"

change it to

xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"

best regards

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it.  I wish it were that simple.  It's like the graphics are not uploading.